# Automating Photo Editing: Cropping and resolution (GIMP as best option?)

Tags: gimp

For all of you that genuinely and kindly want to help, the next two paragraphs aren't for you. I thank you in advance for your helpfulness. The next two paragraphs are for moderators who are power hungry and wish to abuse their powers.

---

First off, **no where in the following do I ask for someone to write a script for me**. Instead I am asking if there might already exist a solution for which I, a novice, may not be aware. (If you doubt my sincerity, look at my previous posts where I post scripts when able). Alternatively, I am asking for guidance on what I might reference to achieve my very CLEAR AND CONCISE objectives. I have detailed below what I know and what I can do and cited that I lack the knowledge to link them together. *The help I need is a clear starting point to learn how to accomplish the objectives I have detailed or direction toward an alternative that has already solved this problem or comes close to solving this problem*.

So, let me repeat my question and emphasize that I am not seeking someone to write a script for me but to point out where I should look next to make progress on my short-comings in knowledge. If you have the power of the moderator and are offended I am asking for where to start my journey to find/develop a solution, please just move along and allow for someone more benevolent to hopefully come across this and offer advice. **We all start at zero when learning something new and this is my zero.** I would appreciate my detailed and specific question not to be shutdown because you are bothered someone is trying to learn something new and asking for help.

---

### My Question / Problem on Automating Editing of Photos (probably with GIMP)

I do not know scripting in GIMP and am a relative novice in photo editing. I can get by when it comes to editing one photo at a time. However, I am hoping to find a solution or easy way **to learn the basics of how to** automate the following.

The input images are of TIFF format (one image per file) and of much higher resolution than that the desired output. To start, by hand, using a `selection box` with a `4:3` fixed ratio (I know how to do this), I will select the desired content I would like; then I would like to automate the following steps either through a tool that may exist for which I do not presently know, a solution I haven't even contemplated in this posting, or through guidance in designing a script that automates the following basic algorithm:

1. Crop to selection
2. Change the resolution to 1600x1200 (5.62429796 px/mm)
3. Export the file with the same base name as a JPG image
4. Close the current image (without overwriting original TIFF)

**Each of these four tasks I know how to do as stand-alone tasks within GIMP**. However, I have no idea where to start when it comes to combining them into an automated action. As I expect to do this to hundreds (if not eventually thousands) of photos, finding/developing a solution that automates the task once I have hand-selected the content I desire would be wonderful.

With my GIMP skill set, the most expeditious solution I can personally develop at this moment would be to crop the image to the desired content and save as a TIFF with appended file name like `"base cropped.tif"`. Then, I could use ImageMagick's CLI to batch adjust the resolution (which I know how to do).

A GIMP solution such as the one I described feels like it would be the most efficient when it comes to minimizing how much time I have to spend in front of my computer on this specific project. **If you have guidance that would allow my novice abilities to achieve this using GIMP or if you have any suggestions on how I can make the process quicker (using something other than GIMP - that is free - for instance), your advice is welcomed and appreciated**. Note, I cannot automate the selection process itself because the location of desired content will change with each photo (sometimes it will be most of the original photo and other times it will be 1/4 of the original photo located in a non-centered location).

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of closed question [Gimp automation: Crop fixed ratio and change resolution](https://superuser.com/questions/1583077/gimp-automation-crop-fixed-ratio-and-change-resolution)

Comment: This [minus the rant] might be better on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions This is pretty easy to do in Photoshop, but idk Gimp at all.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @ Anaksunaman, I am using Windows 10 though I am familiar with Ubuntu and can run it in a VM if need be.

Comment: @Tetsujin, thanks for the alternate forum suggestion. I will look into that.